# Removing an entry from a WebBackForwardList

Tags: cocoa, list, webkit

I am trying to remove an entry from the `WebBackForwardList` of a `WebView` in a Cocoa application. Is there any way to do this? Or a way to prevent a specific entry being added to the list in the first place?